# Ant Script Example

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I would like to make a very simple ant script that does 1 thing, which is to bulid a jar file.  But when I try to use a very simple example, it fails due to dependancies on jars that my source depends on.  So, How you you specify jars that there are jars that need to be in the class path when building an Ant target.

```
<project name="project" default="default">
<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="//tomcat/common/lib"/>
<description> description </description>

<!-- ================================= 
      target: default              
     ================================= -->
<target name="default" depends="compile" description="description">
    <jar destfile="/path/to/dir/Library.jar">

    </jar>
</target>
  <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you post the example? The ant Jar task by itself should not fail for dependencies, maybe your buildfile is also compiling the src before creating the jar. If that is the case you need to specify the classpath attribute.

Comment: So now that we can see the example its clear that the problem is the javac task which is missing the classpath attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example you can just put libs inside javac:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/lib1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/lib2.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't entirely clear - I suspect you mean you want to compile your source (with the `javac` task) and *then* build a jar file from the results. If that's not the case, I don't see where your source dependencies come into it. If that *is* the case, then the `jar` task is irrelevant.

In the [`javac`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task, use the classpath attribute to specify other jar dependencies.

Comment: I will look at the javac task, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an ANT script generated by using the Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard. This is a project that updates stats on a Google Spreadsheet for a small fantasy baseball league with some friends.  It gets the stats by scraping ESPN.com player pages.

Class-Path attribute inside the `manifest` element is used to set the classpath used by the jar.  This defaulted "." but I had to add my src path explicitly so that log4j would pick up log4j.properties.

`zipfileset` elements are external jars used by my source that I wanted to be included with my jar.  I suspect this might be what you're looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project cob_fantasy_baseball">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="C:/workspace/cob_fantasy_baseball/cob_fantasy_baseball.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.me.cob_fantasy_baseball.UpdateCobStats"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value=".;src/com/me/cob_fantasy_baseball"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="C:/workspace/cob_fantasy_baseball/classes"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/workspace/gdata/java/lib/gdata-core-1.0.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/workspace/gdata/java/lib/gdata-spreadsheet-2.0.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/workspace/jericho-html-2.6/lib/jericho-html-2.6.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/workspace/apache-log4j-1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/workspace/jaf-1.1.1/activation.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/workspace/javamail-1.4.2/mail.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/workspace/javamail-1.4.2/lib/smtp.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="C:/workspace/cob_fantasy_baseball/src/com/me/cob_fantasy_baseball"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Also, here's a link to the Ant documentation for the jar task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ant file we use to build the Timeline opensource project. It is pretty straight forward. It doesn't build a jar, but it does use libraries to minimize JS files.

http://simile-widgets.googlecode.com/svn/timeline/trunk/build.xml

Larry